# Use Applescript to Enter command into Terminal but do not Execute

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

Using Applescript, is it possible to open a new Terminal and enter the command into the terminal but do not run it?

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "echo Hello"
end tell
```

This code will type the line `echo Hello` into the Terminal and run it. Can we avoid the execution?

Answer (score 1):

Good case for System Events app and emulating keystrokes:

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate -- only needed if Terminal may not be running

tell application "System Events"        
    tell application process "Terminal"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "echo Hello"
    end tell        
end tell
```